# How to set the scrollTop to the top of a div contanier?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list where are `li` with triger id. I need, when you click on `li` you scroll down the page to the container with the same id. I have this script, but, when I click on `li`you scroll on the top page.

```
(function($) {
$(function() {
var lop = "<ol>"; 
$('.boxes-section .box-section-item .btText h2 strong').each(function() { 
let uid = "ID-"+Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(99999)); 
lop+="<li data-trigger='"+uid+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</li>"; 
$(this).attr('id', uid); 
}); 
lop+="</ol>";
$('.listofparticipants').html(lop).show();
$(".listofparticipants ol li").click(function() {
  var extraspace = $('header#header').height()+$('#wpadminbar').height()+$('#wpfront-notification-bar').height();
  extraspace = extraspace+40;
  $('html, body').delay(2000).animate({scrollTop: $("#"+$(this).attr('data-trigger')).offset().top-extraspace }, 1000);
});

});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$(function() {
    let lop = "<ol>";
    $('.boxes-section .box-section-item .btText h2 strong').each(function() {
        let uid = "ID-"+Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(99999));
        lop += "<li data-trigger='"+uid+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</li>";
        $(this).attr('id', uid);
    });
    lop += "</ol>";
    $('.listofparticipants').html(lop).show();
    $(document).on("click", ".listofparticipants ol li", function() {
        var extraspace = $('header#header').height() + $('#wpadminbar').height() + $('#wpfront-notification-bar').height();
        extraspace = extraspace + 40;
        $('html, body').delay(2000).animate({scrollTop: $("#" + $(this).attr('data-trigger')).offset().top - extraspace}, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: nothing. Do all the same. Scroll to top page